# Pattern finding approaches

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, signal-processing

I'm looking for patterns in a signal.
I had used successfully a cross-correlation approach.
However, I found some references to Gibbs sampling approaches for finding patterns.

My question is: 
Are both approaches complementary one to the other, or
are they redundant in some way?

Comment: What kind of "patterns" are you interested in?

Comment: Numeric patterns range -2:+2 with 2 decimal points in several sequences of numbers. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I was thinking of things like: peak detection, structural changes, distortion in the frequency domain, etc. Giving more context might help to get precise and helpful responses.

Comment: Excuse my vagueness. I'm looking for common "structures", "motifs", in sequences of numbers. i.e: seq1=0.2 0.3 -0.4 1.2 0 0.9 0.7 0.1 0.8 0.9; seq2=0.3 0.3 -0.4 1.1 0 0.9 0.6 0.3 0.8 0.8; You can tell both sequences are closely related and if you plot them you will see they share a common "pattern". But my question is more theoretical if you want. What I want to know is if by using both approaches I will get a better prediction than by using just one of them or not. If the combination of the 2 is better, which should I use first. I didn't find documentation about this...

Comment: ... Can you recommend me a paper or book that covers the topic? i.e. Gibbs sampling and cross-correlation; EM and cross-correlation; MCMC and cross-correlation. No matter in what area. What I need to know is if they are used in combination and how that combination is applied. Thanks. Diego

Comment: Unfortunately not. However, given the additional details you provided someone will perhaps come up with some good recommendations.